# Código que se ejecuta pero no parece terminar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Diseñé un juego de mesa en el que dibujo un texto en el que pregunto el color que el jugador quiere elegir antes de jugar. Entonces debería desaparecer pero no desaparece.

```
def runGame():
    # Juega un solo juego cada vez que se llama a esta función.
    # Restablece el tablero y el juego.

    mainBoard, moveBoard = getNewBoard()
    resetBoard(mainBoard) 
    # Reset the sailors and boat
    sailors = []
    white_sailors = []
    black_sailors = []

    sailors = resetSailors(sailors,mainBoard) 
    turn = random.choice(['player1', 'player2'])

    # Dibuja el tablero de partida
    drawBoard(mainBoard, sailors)
    # ask the player what color they want.
    playerTile, computerTile = enterPlayerTile() # <-- AQUÍ EL CÓDIGO QUE MUESTRA EL TEXTO

    # Crea los objetos Surface y Rect para los botones "New Game" y "Hints"
    newGameSurf = FONT.render('New Game', True, TEXTCOLOR, TEXTBGCOLOR2)
    newGameRect = newGameSurf.get_rect()
    newGameRect.topright = (WINDOWWIDTH - 8, 10)

def enterPlayerTile():
    # Dibuja el texto y maneja los eventos de clic del mouse para permitir # el jugador elige el color que quiere ser. Devuelve
    # [WHITE_TILE, BLACK_TILE] si el jugador elige ser WHITE,
    # [BLACK_TILE, WHITE_TILE] si Black.

    # Create the text.
    textSurf = FONT.render('Do you want to be white or black?', True, TEXTCOLOR, TEXTBGCOLOR1)
    textRect = textSurf.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2), int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2))

    xSurf = BIGFONT.render('White', True, TEXTCOLOR, TEXTBGCOLOR1)
    xRect = xSurf.get_rect()
    xRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) - 60, int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) + 40)

    oSurf = BIGFONT.render('Black', True, TEXTCOLOR, TEXTBGCOLOR1)
    oRect = oSurf.get_rect()
    oRect.center = (int(WINDOWWIDTH / 2) + 60, int(WINDOWHEIGHT / 2) + 40)

    while True:
        # Keep looping until the player has clicked on a color.
        checkForQuit()
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousex, mousey = event.pos
                if xRect.collidepoint( (mousex, mousey) ):
                    return [WHITE_TILE, BLACK_TILE]
                elif oRect.collidepoint( (mousex, mousey) ):
                    return [BLACK_TILE, WHITE_TILE]

        # Draw the screen.
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(textSurf, textRect)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(xSurf, xRect)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(oSurf, oRect)
        pygame.display.update()
        MAINCLOCK.tick(FPS)
```

Mientras que deberia crearse los objetos Surface y Rect para los botones "New Game" y "Hints" despues `enterPlayerTile()` pero no desaparecie, incluso si dejo la función después de clic.

Por el contrario, en [el código que me inspiró](https://inventwithpython.com/flippy.py) no tengo este problema.

Si lo necesites [aqui esta el repositorio de mi entero codigo](https://github.com/antoinecomp/pirates).

Comment: Tienes dos ciclos `while` infinitos dentro de `runGame` (linea 109 y 131) en los que no se actualiza la pantalla. Mientras no salgas de ambos ciclos el texto no desaparece porque la pantalla no se ha actualizado, la pantalla se actualiza en la linea 167, después de que ambos ciclos terminen...

Comment: @FJSevilla Entendido, en este caso, intenté agregar dos intentos agregando un `MAINCLOCK.tick (FPS)`: antes de eliminar el texto de elección del color y después de agregar el nuevo cuando creo los objetos Surface y Rect para los botones "New Game" y "Hints" pero no se elimina el texto de eleccion y no se agrega el nuevo